# Views handling JSON Post-ed to a Django URI not working on the production nginx server

Tags: django, json, post, nginx

I have written a django view that receives data in a JSON format via POST Method, and I return a JSON Response to it.
Though my View is working perfectly on the local Development Server, it is spitting out a 500 Internal Server when I am POST-ing the data onto a NGINX-DJANGO Setup on my Production Server.

Thanks in adavnce on help!

Comment: Please set `Debug=True` in `settings.py` and post the stacktrace here.

Comment: I am testing the view via python script that posts a JSON, and the response when printed just gives me HTTP 500